# Detect page rendering status in Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I need a way to check when AngularJS completes fully the browser render so that my headless browser PhantomJS can crawl and return the full page html.

Normally, i'd use some kind of Id, class name of a html element for phantomjs to detect if the page is rendered or not but in SPA like angularjs it's hard to do the same because I cannot check if all sections in a page have completed the rendering.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    string url = String.Format("http://localhost:12345/{0}", fragment);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    var header = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("footer")));  >> bad because footer is always there, not in angularjs code
    content = driver.PageSource;
}
```

So I wonder if there's a way in Angularjs detect the site has completed the render, then i can mark it somewhere like `<input id="renderStatus" name="renderStatus" ng-if="renderStatus>0" type="hidden" value="{{renderStatus}}">`

UPdated: i tried $viewContentLoaded and $stateChangeSuccess but not achieve what I like

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$q', 
    function ($rootScope, $q) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
                $rootScope.renderStatus = 1;
            });
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: what phantomjs wrapper are you using?